# is it possible to forward ios sms message to server or android device

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

I have two phone, one is ios and another is android. Now I need to make the sms message forward from ios to android automatically. is it possible to forward the ios sms to some server side? I have already found the https://github.com/Finb/bark-server that could forward the sms messsage from android to ios. But it seems impossible to forward sms from ios to android?